# How to stop a service when updating another in Debian

Tags: debian, systemd, supervisord

In Debian, how can I stop all [supervisord](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/supervisor/supervisord.1.en.html) processes before upgrading/restarting [postgres](https://linux.die.net/man/1/postgres) and start them after [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/server-start.html) is finished?

Background: I would like to use unattended upgrades. If the database is stopped the processes should also be turned off to avoid data loss.

Comment: I'm on Debian..

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with supervisord, so bear with me here and let me know if my assumptions are wrong. As I understand it, supervisord starts other processes. Assuming stopping and starting supervisord itself also stops/starts the processes it controls, then the easiest I think would be to adjust the supervisord systemd service to add a BindsTo=postgresql.service. This would be done, as I prefer, not by editing the supervisord.service file itself, but by creating a directory /etc/systemd/system/supervisord.service.d/ and placing in it a file named like bindpostgresql.conf and then add to that file:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=postgresql.service
```

Alternatively, If you do not want to start/stop supervisord itself, but just the processes it controls, then a kind of hackish easy way would be to adjust postgresql.service, the same way as above, to add a ExecStartPost=-/path/to/script/startprocesses.sh and ExecStop=-/path/to/script/stopprocesses.sh settings to run a script that tells supervisord to start/stop your processes (note the "-" is important to not make postgresql itself be marked as failed when the script fails). You could also put the supervisorctl command in place of the /path/to/script.sh if it is only 1 short command.

On another note, you should be very careful using unattended upgrades. You should make sure you have a monitoring system that notifies you in case things do not work after attempted upgrades.

Thanks!
-Dan